# How to have a maximum RPS metric in CloudWatch without losing the precision?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, requests-per-second

I’m working on a graph in CloudWatch which will show the maximum **requests per second(RPS)** at any given time at the past and we would like to have it without the loss of precigion with a time after aggreration happened. By without a loss I mean that we would like to see what was the maximum RPS let's say a year ago at any given hour.

Our service produces only request count metric. The TPS metric is currently calculated with CloudWatch `RATE()` function. And we are going to produce it with a [High resolution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch_concepts.html#Resolution_definition).

But the problem is that I wasn't able to find a way to tell CloudWatch to store calculated TPS metric and aggregate it with the `Maximun` aggregation method. So, after aggregation is made by CloudWatch, we will be loosing the precision of max TPS as it'll continue to be calculated as total amount of requests happened withing the period and the period is constantly increasing based on [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch_concepts.html#metrics-retention) and at the end of the day we will be receiving some avarage RPS instead of maximum.

Is it somehow achivable by CloudWatch metrics?